# How to get callback by text hyperlink in Telegram bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot with command /list, that show list of something, for example:

There are some list:

[Alex](https://link.com)

[Ivan](https://link.com)

[Pier](https://link.com)

I want to make names clickable, and show detailed information on click. But how I can get callback on that action with telegram api?
I don't want to use buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to navigate in the Telegram bot:

1. **Buttons** (the easiest). Canonical way for any action, when user already in bot. Here is [how to use](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) inline keyboard buttons API.
2. **Deep links** (seems like an answer). Usually it is used to navigate user from the outside to your Telegram bot concrete action `https://t.me/yourAwesomeBot?start=concrete_action`, [read more](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#deep-linking)
3. **Telegram Web App** (outstanding). Just build an a fully-fledge Web App inside your bot an make your fancy dreams come true, [read more](https://core.telegram.org/bots/features#web-apps)